# How do I solve a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?

Tags: java, parsing, out-of-memory

I am writing some code to parse a very large flat text file into objects which are persisted to a database. This is working on sections of the file (i.e. if I 'top' the first 2000 lines), but I am running into a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error when I try and process the full file.

I am using a BufferedReader to read the file line by line, and I was under the impression that this negates the requirement to load the entire text file into memory. Hopefully my code is fairly self-explanatory. I have run my code through the Eclipse Memory Analyser, which informs me that:

> The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0x27ee0478 main keeps local variables with total size 69,668,888 (98.76%) bytes.
>   The memory is accumulated in one instance of "char[]" loaded by "<system class loader>"**

Helpful comments greatly appreciated!

Jonathan

```
public ArrayList<Statement> parseGMIFile(String filePath)
            throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<Statement>();

        // Statement Properties
        String sAccount = "";
        String sOffice = "";
        String sFirm = "";
        String sDate1 = "";
        String sDate2 = "";
        Date date = new Date();
        StringBuffer sData = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        String prevCode = "";
        int lineCounter = 1;
        int globalLineCounter = 1;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                // We extract the GMI code from the end of the first line
                String newCode = line.substring(GMICODE_START_POS).trim();

                // Extract date
                if (newCode.equals(prevCode)) {

                    if (lineCounter == DATE_LINE) { 
                        sDate1 = line.substring(DATE_START_POS, DATE_END_POS).trim();}

                    if (lineCounter == DATE_LINE2) {
                        sDate2 = line.substring(DATE_START_POS, DATE_END_POS).trim();}

                    if (sDate1.equals("")){
                        sDate1 = sDate2;}
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
                        try {
                            date=formatter.parse(sDate1);

                        } catch (ParseException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                   



                    sFirm = line.substring(FIRM_START_POS, FIRM_END_POS);
                    sOffice = line.substring(OFFICE_START_POS, OFFICE_END_POS);
                    sAccount = line.substring(ACCOUNT_START_POS,
                            ACCOUNT_END_POS);
                    lineCounter++;
                    globalLineCounter++;
                    sData.append(line.substring(0, END_OF_DATA)).append("\n");

                } else {

                    // Instantiate New Statement Object
                    Statement stmt = new Statement(sAccount, sOffice, sFirm,
                            date, sData.toString());


                    // Add to collection
                    statements.add(stmt);

                    // log.info("-----------NEW STATEMENT--------------");
                    sData.setLength(0);
                    lineCounter = 1;
                }
                prevCode = newCode;
        }
        return statements;
    }
```

```
STACKTRACE: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbPopulator' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
    at services.GMILogParser.parseGMIFile(GMILogParser.java:133)
    at services.DBPopulator.init(DBPopulator.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1468)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: If you are not on a server VM, the default heap space is 64 MB, you might try to increase it to 512MB or more.

Answer (score 5):

Adding more memory in the start parameters is IMHO a mistake. Those parameters are application wide. And may penalize by increasing `gc` times. Moreover, you might not know the size in advance.

You use `MemoryMappedFiles` and look at the [java.nio.*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) to do so. Doing so you can load as you read, and the memory is not placed in the ordinary memory space.

By reading at a low level you do it in chunks of variable length. And the speed is important. If your file is large, it may take too much time to read it. And the quantity of `Objects` you store in `JVM` makes the `GC` works and the application slows down.
From the java reference:

- A `byte buffer` can be allocated as a direct buffer, in which case the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform `native I/O operations` directly upon it.
- A `byte buffer` can be created by mapping a region of a file directly into memory, in which case a few additional file-related operations defined in the MappedByteBuffer class are available.
- A `byte buffer` provides access to its content as either a heterogeneous or homogeneous sequence of binary data of any non-boolean primitive type, in either big-endian or little-endian byte order.

Comment: Here comes my noob question of the day :D.... Wasn't nio performing worse than plain old IO ? Or was is just related to multi-threaded env? I recall reading something related to how old io outclassed nio, but cannot find a reference link.

Comment: ok found the article I was referring. http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is the statements object that is growing too large? If so, maybe you should persist it to the database in batches instead of all at once?

Comment: Hi Daniel, that is a good suggestion. I must be creating an enormous ArrayList at the moment.

Comment: That would add the need for a database, which at this point we don't know if the application contains. And we should anyway insert in the DB from the file.

Comment: But the purpose is inserting to a DB right? The first line of the question is: "I am writing some code to parse a very large flat text file into objects which are persisted to a database. "

Answer (score 2):

It seems your application is using the default memory allocated by the VM (about 64 MB if I remember correctly). Since your application is a special-purpose one, I'd suggest increasing the memory available for the application (e.g. running the app using `java -Xmx256m` would allow it to use up to 256 MB of RAM). You could also try running it using the server VM (`java -server yourapp`), which will try to optimize things a bit.

Comment: But that would only solve the problem until 256MB is used, right? It would probably be better to find what is using so much memory and then e.g. do the persistence in batches (as I try to do in my answer).

Comment: @DanielLundmark Yes, sure. I certainly agree, you should look for the bottleneck. But it would also help to use more memory; a 64 MB buffer is not large IMHO. For such specific-purpose applications I wouldn't mind using a 1 GB buffer for example, especially if it's going to be run once or so.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that can happen here:
if your file is bigger than half your heap and does not contain any linebreaks in.readLine() would try to read the whole file and fail in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M` has solved my `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error`.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

code seems right to me. maybe I should have used StringBuffer in place of String.

String are pretty nasty in java, for each modification you perform on them, a new object is created, and refs can remain anywhere in the code.

Usually I read file lines inside a private method using local vars, just to be sure that no ref to String are left around.

The list you're getting back is a list of beans with String properties? If so, change 'em to StringBuffer and rerun the profiling.

Let me know if this helped you.

Regards,

M.

Comment: I'm having some problem changing the code so that rather having it add the 'Statement' object to the ArrayList, it simply passes it to the Database Service Object that inserts it into the DB.

Comment: Sounds good, but beware of performance problems. Usually batch statements perform faster than repetitions of single statements. If performance drops, you may try a mixed solution (using a window of n statements passed all together to the Db service)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sData causes the overflow. There should be several (million?) statements in the text with the same GMI code.

Accumulations by char[] means either String or StringBuilder. Since it fails with resizing StringBuilder, it should be the reason.

Just try to output sData to stdout for debugging and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I would think so. This is especially funny as the string in sData is nowhere used, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Ingo It's used to accumulate string representation of a statement. As soon as statement ended it is used to build Statement:

Statement stmt = new Statement(sAccount, sOffice, sFirm, date, sData.toString());

Comment: TRADE   SETTL  AT                               JOURNAL DESCRIPTION                           CC    DEBIT/CREDIT           
 ------- ------- --                               ------------------------------                -- --------------------      
  9/21/1  9/21/1 EH                               2494747 /EQY/SCL/1171 HK Equ/                 HD         803,808.60DR      
                                                  0       /CNE1000004Q8/6109893                                              
  9/21/1  9/21/1 EH                               2494748

Comment: Basically, it's working... and as I reset sData to 0 at the end of each loop iteration (which doesn't include THAT many lines), why would this be causing the overflow?

Comment: Although, when I comment out the code to append the data into sData, the script is able to parse the entire 1.2GB file without a problem.

Comment: So I guess I need to find a more memory-efficient way to do this!

Comment: The logic is crazy anyway. Looks to me like you make a statement on the very first line, using empty strings for office, etc (which you set only if something in the new line is equal to the old one.)

Comment: @jkhamler Try to use StringBuilder

Comment: @jkhamler Well, the trick is saving a String copy of sData in a statement. You said there is about 1.2GB and all this data is saved in statements. You'd better to re-organize the process to eliminate saving a copy of statement or divide data to small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to replace the line (if your using JDK 6, substring memory problem was solved in JDK 7)

```
String newCode = line.substring(GMICODE_START_POS).trim();
```

Replace line:

```
String newCode = new String(line.substring(GMICODE_START_POS));
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem a few months back

I used `Scanner` class:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

instead of:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```